# Implementing a binary search tree with duplicate values

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a binary search tree that takes duplicate values and stores the value in one node with the number of times that node occurs as "num". I have implemented a function which adds nodes and if there are duplicate nodes, the number of times that node occurs is shown in the output.

I am trying to create a count function that counts the number of times an element occurs in the tree. so for example count("code") should return 2.

I am also trying implement a deletefunction that removes a value, but if there are duplicates, then only one of the value should be removed. For example delete("code") should print out (code,1), And if "num" is 0, the whole node should be removed.

This is what i have done so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val,l,r):
        self._data = val
        self.num = 1
        self._leftChild = l
        self._rightChild = r


    # prints the node and all its children in a string
    def __str__(self):  
        st = "("+str(self._data)+", "+str(self.num)+") -> ["
        if self._leftChild != None:
            st += str(self._leftChild)
        else: st += "None"
        if self._rightChild != None:
            st += ", "+str(self._rightChild)
        else: st += ", None"
        return st + "]"

    def updateChild(self, oldChild, newChild):
        if self._leftChild == oldChild:
            self._leftChild = newChild
        elif self._rightChild == oldChild:
            self._rightChild = newChild
        else: raise Exception("updateChild error")

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.root)

    def isEmpty(self):    
        return self.root == None 

    def search(self, val, depth=1):
        if not self.root:
            return 0, 0
        elif self.root._data == val:
            return depth, self.root.num
        elif val < self.root._data:
            return search(self.root._leftChild, val, depth + 1)
        else:
            return search(self.root._rightChild, val, depth + 1

    def add(self, val):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(val,None,None)

        else:
            pointer = self.root
            while True:
                if val < pointer._data:
                    if pointer._leftChild == None:
                        pointer._leftChild = Node(val,None,None)
                        break
                    pointer = pointer._leftChild
                elif val == pointer._data:
                        pointer.num += 1
                        break
                else:
                    if pointer._rightChild == None:
                        pointer._rightChild = Node(val,None,None)
                        break
                    pointer = pointer._rightChild




    def count(self, val):
        pointer = self.root
        count = 0
        while pointer != None:
            pointer = self.search(pointer,val)
            if pointer != None:
                count += 1
                count = pointer.num
                pointer = pointer._rightChild
        return count




    def delete(self,val):
        if self.root == None:
            return
        if self.root._data == val: 
            return self._removeRoot()
        parentNode = None
        currentNode = self.root
        while currentNode != None and currentNode._data !=val:
            if val < currentNode.data:
                parentNode = currentNode
                currentNode = currentNode._leftChild
            else:
                parentNode = currentNode
                currentNode = currentNode._rightChild
        if currentNode != None:
            return self._removeNode(currentNode,parentNode)

    # removes the node currentNode from the tree altogether
    def _removeNode(self,currentNode,parentNode):
        self.size -= 1
        # 3 cases to consider:
        # 1. the node to be removed is a leaf
        if currentNode._leftChild == currentNode._rightChild == None:
            parentNode.updateChild(currentNode,None)
        # 2.node to be removed has exactly one child
        elif currentNode._leftChild == None or currentNode._rightChild == None:
        if currentNode._leftChild != None:
            parentNode.updateChild(currentNode,currentNode._leftChild)
        else:
            parentNode.updateChild(currentNode,currentNode._rightChild)
    # 3. node to be removed has both children
        else:
            parentMinNode = currentNode
            minNode = currentNode._rightChild
            while minNode._leftChild != None:
                parentMinNode = minNode
                minNode = minNode._leftChild
            parentMinNode.updateChild(minNode,minNode._rightChild)
            parentNode.updateChild(currentNode,minNode)
            minNode._leftChild = currentNode._leftChild
            minNode._rightChild = currentNode._rightChild

    def _removeRoot(self):
        parentNode = Node(None,self.root,None)
        self._removeNode(self.root,parentNode)
        self.root = parentNode._leftChild
```

and here is an example using the above classes:

```
t = Tree()
t.add("code"); t.add("pyt"); t.add("hello"); t.add("code")
t.add("java"); t.add("math"); t.add("Comp")


Output: (code, 2) -> [(Comp, 1) -> [None, None], (pyt, 1) -> [(hello, 1) -> [None, (java, 1) -> [None, (math, 1) -> [None, None]]], None]]
```

After this when I do:

```
print(t.count("code"),t.delete("code"),t.count("code"),t.size)
```

It should print:

```
 2 None 1 6
```

And result should be:

```
 (cat, 1) -> [(car, 1) -> [None, (cart, 1) -> [None, None]], (cav, 1) -> [None, (put, 1) ->
[(cs, 1) -> [None, None], None]]]
```

Comment: Hey! What is your question or the problem you're having?

Comment: I am trying to implement a remove function and am not sure how to remove the value and decrease the "num" value.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify your question: currently the delete method always deletes the node containing the given value, even if `num > 1` and you are asking us how to modify the algorithm so that `if node.num > 1: node.num -= 1; return`?

Comment: Yes. I have added what the output should be at the bottom. Sorry about indentation

Comment: You can either modify `_removeNode` so that the first thing that it does is checking `currentNode.num > 1` and if it is true then all it does is `currentNode.num -= 1; return`, otherwise it proceeds like it currently does. A cleaner solution might be to move this check outside `_removeNode` and place it before calling it. So inside `delete` just before the call to `_removeNode` do: `if  currentNode.num == 1: self._removeNode(currentNode,...) else: currentNode.num -= 1`.